# How do I call a JavaScript function in the webpage displayed by an iframe, from a TypeScript file in Ionic 4?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

How can I call a JavaScript function with parameters on it (`foo('bar','yadda')`) from my `.page.ts` file?

I have an Ionic 4 app with a page with an `<iframe>` on it that I need to call a JavaScript in the page displayed by the `<iframe>`. The `.html` file looks like this:

```
<ion-header>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <iframe class='webPage' name="samplePage" [src]="cleanURL" width="100%" height="100%">
  </iframe>
</ion-content>
```

I intialize the the `<iframe>` in my .page.ts file like this:

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
  this.url = "https://example.com/mylegacysite"+ '?' + this.someParameter;
  this.cleanURL = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.url);
}
```

It initializes fine. But later on, it would be much more efficient to be able to run the the JavaScript function on https://example.com/mylegacysite instead of updating `this.cleanURL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With different domains, it is not possible to call methods or access the iframe's content document directly.

You need to use [cross-document messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

For example in the top window:

```
myIframe.contentWindow.postMessage('Hello', '*');
```

and in your iframe:

```
window.onmessage = function(e){
if (e.data == 'Hello') {
    alert('It works!');
}
```

};